# Counting the length of each element inside a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

My task is to print only the words that are shorter than 4 characters. I have tried it countless ways, but there is always an error. Would very much appreciate any help.

```
b = find_short_words(['dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'horse', 'pangolin'])

short_words = [word for word in b if len(name)]<5
```

Tried loops with len function, but it always returns an error.

Comment: Your second line is almost right (at least it would be if `b` were the original list of words), but it refers to a variable `name` that hasn't been defined yet, and the `len(word) < 5` condition is split in half with part of it dangling outside of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a list with a integer, which is invalid.

```
words = ['dog', 'cat', 'turtle', 'horse', 'pangolin']
short_words = [word for word in words if len(word) < 5] # put <5 inside loop
print(short_words)
```